# How to create a custom locale with a custom NSDecimalSeparator value?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

I'm having trouble with

```
+ (NSDecimalNumber *)decimalNumberWithString:(NSString *)numericString locale:(NSDictionary *)locale
```

Because I want to provide very high precision values programmatically to have no floating-point errors initially, apple gives me the only option to rely on a wonky locale.

So the documentation says pretty encrypted:

> Parameters: ... 
>   locale
>   A dictionary
>   that defines the locale (specifically
>   the NSDecimalSeparator) to use to
>   interpret the number in numericString.
>
> Discussion
>   The locale parameter determines whether the NSDecimalSeparator is a
>   period (as is used, for example, in
>   the United States) or a comma (as is
>   used, for example, in France).

well, after searching for NSDecimalSeparator in the docs, nothing found. Searching on the net, found that this thing is "deprecated". So currently I do something dangerous like this:

```
NSLocale *usLoc = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
NSDecimalNumber *num = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:str locale:usLoc];
```

So I wonder: If they really need this wonky locale for something crucial like this (I add strings programmatically, no user input), couldn't I somehow create an own locale? That parameter wants an NSDictionary, so the idea:

Could I create an NSMutableDictionary out of that locale Dictionary that comes for -initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US", and then just edit this %?&§! NSDecimalSeparator field?

And another thing that raises my headaches: Why does the parameter ask for an NSDictionary, where I have to pass an NSLocale object? Or is my code wrong? (not tested, since my app is currently totally screwed up ;-) )

Comment: any response to this? I have similar question about creating the NSDictionary that needs to hold and NSLocale

Answer (score 5):

There doesn't appear to be a way to add/modify the values in an instance of `NSLocale`; you can only get the logical locale for the user (`currentLocale` and `autoupdatingCurrentLocale`), the system locale without any changes made by the user in their system preferences (`systemLocale`), or any other named locale that the system knows about (`initWithLocaleIdentifier`).

`NSLocale` responds to the `objectForKey:` message, which is the same message that `NSDictionary` uses; that's why you can use an `NSLocale` even though the method calls for an `NSDictionary`. Since `NSDecimalNumber` is likely only going to look at one value, `NSDecimalSeparator`, I have a feeling you could get away with creating an `NSDictionary` object with that key and pass it as the `locale` parameter, but this might break in the future, since `NSDecimalNumber` expects a full-blown `NSLocale` instance and might be changed to check for other keys.

You are creating these strings programmatically, right? So you can control what decimal separator you use. My recommendation would be to use `.`, and get the en_US locale:

```
NSLocale *us = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
```

The decimal separator is sure to be `.` every time.